# Chosen doesn't work in my MVC environment

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I would like to add chosen in my selectlist,

In cshtml, here is where I want to add "chosen":

```
<span class="step">3.) Select Test:</span>
<select id="SelectedSkateTestId" name="SelectedSkateTestId"></select><br/>             
<span class="step"></span>(start typing test code to search list)<br/>
```

and I add this sentence in the jQuery block:

```
$(function(){
    $("#SelectedSkateTestId").chosen();
});
```

In Browser:
it is failure.

I inspect element, it showed the "chosen" may not cover the selectlist:
the selectlist still there, and there are many class "chosen" tag under dropdownlist.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said...

Comment: Are you trying to get the selected item, or an item with a chosen attribute, from the drop down list?

Comment: I would like to use "chosen" package to my dropdownlist, the id of dropdownlist is "SelectedSakteTestId". But I don't know how it works.Because I have no enough reputation, I can not upload a image.If I can upload a image, it would be more clear.@tbleckert @Brent Mannering

Comment: So "chosen" is a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Can I also suggest submitting a jsfiddle? It may help to understand what you are trying to do.